# Getting error as Page Not Found(Error Code: 404) when trying $http.get to a URL

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

My Grails 3.2.3 app is running on port 9000 and I'm doing a `GET` request to the URL `/api/mail/getUnreadCount` but I'm getting a 404 error to that URL.

My `URLMapping.groovy` having:

```
get "/api/$controller(.$format)?"(action: "index")
get "/api/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action: "show")

"/api/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?" {
    constraints {
        // apply constraints here
    }
}
```

Also help me, how we can enable Grails URL mapping logs?

**Update 1**

```
class MailController {

    static allowedMethods = [index: "GET", getUnreadCount: "GET"]
    .....
    .......
    def getUnreadCount() {
        User currentUserInstance = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
        List counts = userService.getUnreadCounts(currentUserInstance)
        respond(counts)
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to add '/' to '/api/mail/getUnreadCount' so it looks like `/api/mail/getUnreadCount/`

Comment: Yes I tried, but still issue is there

Comment: I think the issue is your grails application is not properly running on 9000 port.Check if you able to open grails homepage by hitting **http://localhost:9000** . if it is working ,then is it showing your **mail** controller?

Comment: Yes, localhost:9000 is working fine, even when I am accessing the index action then also it is working fine. I am hitting the URL like, http://localhost:9000/api/mail It is working and it is showing the list from mailController

Comment: so what's the issue?. you are saying that **localhost:9000/api/mail** is working but **localhost:9000/api/mail/getUnreadCount** is throwing 404?. Then it must be some typing error.

Comment: I have checked the same .It's working fine

Comment: Can you post me a example or explain me.
I am not getting error when I am trying like
`localhost:9000/api/mail/getUnreadCount/10` or
`localhost:9000/api/mail/getUnreadCount/10?max=10`

Comment: Also check question once again. I have updated it sometime back

Comment: can you show me your **mail** controller or **getUnreadCount** function

Comment: Updated my Question with the code

Answer (score 1):

It is expected that you have `getUnreadCount.gsp` in views/mail directory to get the output from `respond`

.. and for the code you provided, if you dont have any view, you should get `Error 500` not 404.

In your code, put

> formats: ['xml', 'json']

or explicitely mention view

> view: "showCount"

or try `render` method instead

**Update**

Btw, please remove

```
get "/api/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action: "show")
```

When you hit /api/mail/getUnreadCount, this mapping causes `$id = getUnreadCount`, and you don't have any action `show` in your controller, which generates **404** error.